# Cómo poner una imagen SVG de logo en materialize?

Tags: css, materialize

Estoy trabajando con Materialize, quisiera saber si es posible usar una imagen **SVG** de logo en mi barra de navegación?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que los archivos SVG no tienen ni ancho ni alto y por eso se quiebran y no figuran.

Aquí hay una respuesta que puede ayudarte:

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1904